# Angular components and using them

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm pretty new to angular2+ and would like to understand how I could use the already built framework which is built on Angular + Material2
https://github.com/codetok/cdk-admin

I have opened an issue there but I'm very excited to use it so I'm asking it on SO.

I would like to use a component as component and it's actually rendered with the router. Someone can give me a ref or an example of how I would be able in that context use the component.

https://github.com/codetok/cdk-admin/issues/4

Update: It's the module I want to run the application.

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardCrmComponent } from './dashboard-crm.component';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { DashboardWidgetModule } from '../dashboard-widget/dashboard-widget.module';
import { TablesModule } from '../tables/tables.module';
import { FilterTableComponent } from '../tables/filter-table/filter-table.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DashboardCrmComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes),
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatCardModule,
    DashboardWidgetModule,
    TablesModule //here is the module
  ],
  declarations: [DashboardCrmComponent, FilterTableComponent],
  exports: []
})
export class DashboardCrmModule {
}
```

An error I'm getting:

```
core.js:1440 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
    'cdk-filter-table' is not a known element:
    1. If 'cdk-filter-table' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'cdk-filter-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap>
      [ERROR ->]<cdk-filter-table></cdk-filter-table>
    </div>
    <!--<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap>
    "): ng:///DashboardCrmModule/DashboardCrmComponent.html@1:2
    Error: Template parse errors:
    'cdk-filter-table' is not a known element:
    1. If 'cdk-filter-table' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'cdk-filter-table' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap>
      [ERROR ->]<cdk-filter-table></cdk-filter-table>
    </div>
```

Comment: npm install @angular/material @angular/cdk and then npm start should solve your problem

Comment: @VinkoVorih I have done it before. It does not work. It's somehow related to the part that modules aren't loaded. I actually don't understand - why? Even if I add specific TablesModule to the one I want to run it. It's still show's that error.

Comment: can you provide to me app.module.ts and component.html

Comment: Yep. your import is wrong. If you are using Material table it should be:
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';

or if you are using cdk check this: https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/api

Comment: @VinkoVorih here :https://github.com/codetok/cdk-admin/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @VinkoVorih it's already implemented in the compoent I wish to use. If I run it via route it does work without any issue. I would like to reuse it.

Comment: add "import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk/table';" to app.module.ts file